# "replaceWith" not altering contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The directive replaceWith as used in the code below only changes the target content once.  If I send any other object the alert shows the proper value but not the div.

```
    function identify (thisobj) {
        alert(thisobj.value);
        $("#test").replaceWith(thisobj.value);
    }
```

The target element is shown below.

```
    <div id="canvas_container">
        <div id="test">This is a test</div>
    </div>
```

Various objects are being passed, here, each with a different value.  But though the Alert() reflects the proper content, the #Test only allows a one time change and then it retains that value forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceWith` removes the `#test` element and replaces it with what you set (`thisobj.value`).

To replace an element's *content*, use `.html()` (or `.text()`).

```
function identify (thisobj) {
    alert(thisobj.value);
    $("#test").html(thisobj.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing `#test` with your new element. It won't work again unless the element you replace it with also matches that selector.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

> The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new
>   content in its place with a single call.

Assuming you want to keep the `#test` element, you can use the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to replace the *contents* of it, rather than the element itself.

Comment: @DennisKean - If you just want to replace the text within `#test` you can use the `text` method, or the `html` method, as mentioned in my answer (and the other answers).

Answer (score 2):

`.replaceWith()` substitutes an entire DOM node; you should be using `.html(thisobj.value)` or `.text(thisobj.value)`

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the use of `replaceWith`: it replaces the element you call it on, so after the first use, there is no element `#test` anymore.

You want `text` or maybe `html`:

```
$("#test").text(thisobj.value);
```

If your value contains html, use:

```
$("#test").html(thisobj.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

replaceWith will replace the entire element, to replace the content within #test, use:

```
$("#test").html(thisobj.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into jQuery's text() function? If not, http://api.jquery.com/text/

It may help with replacing text